# nuxt-mail fails with a 504 with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: vue.js, nginx, axios, nuxt.js, nodemailer

I configured nuxt-mail to send emails from our nuxt app.
The baseURL of my app is changed to "https://localhost:3000/app" instead of "https://localhost:3000"
So, nginx redirects all calls to '/' to a static app. And all calls to '/app' to a dynamic app.
The issue is that on production, nuxt-mail is unable to send email through a post to '/app/mail/send'.

1. I tried with setting axios baseURL on *nuxt.config.js* as suggested on the [nuxt-mail npm/github page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-mail)
2. I don't see a path to **send** or **mail** in *.nuxt/router.js*

**file: contact.vue**
Note: WEBSITE_DOMAIN points to https://localhost:3000 locally and valid web domain on production in this format: https://www.production_website.com

> ```
> <script>
> ...
> methods: {
> ...
> sendMail(){
>   this.$axios.post( 
>     this.$config.WEBSITE_DOMAIN+'/app/mail/send', 
>     {
>     ...
>      }
> ...
> }
> ...
> </script>
> ```

**file: nuxt.config.js**

> ```
> ...
> export default{
> ...
> router: {
>     base: '/app/'
>   },
> ...
> }
> ```

**Note:** I did configure the upstream logs from nginx to app server

**Access log from nginx on production**

> 49.205.150.249 - - [04/May/2022:15:30:54 +0000] "POST /app/mail/send HTTP/1.1" 504 167 "https://www.<xxxxxxxxx_NAME>.com/app/contact"
> "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101
> Firefox/99.0"

**Error log from nginx on production**

> 2022/05/04 15:30:54 [error] 2106#2106: *38 upstream timed out (110:
> Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
> client: 49.205.150.249, server: <xxxxxxxxx_NAME>.com, request: "POST
> /app/mail/send HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "https://<xxxxxxxxx_IP>:3000/app/mail/send", host:
> "www.<xxxxxxxxx_NAME>.com", referrer:
> "https://www.<xxxxxxxxx_NAME>.com/app/contact"

What am I missing here? It works perfectly on my staging though.

Comment: can you post the code in the various files?

Comment: There seems to be some kind of auto redirection that happens when we hit /. The call automatically looks for /app (modified base path). Especially for some paths like images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port allowing SMTP on the production instance was not open. On AWS EC2, I needed to enable outbound rules on the corresponding security group.